# using apache digester to parse xml

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-digester

have an xml of the form

```
<Node name="1">
   <Node name="2">
       <Node name="4"></Node>
   </Node>
   <Node name = "3">
       <Node name="5"></Node>
    </Node>
</Node>
```

i want to parse the xml using digester and obtain the following datastructure

```
Node{
 String name;
 List<Node> nodeList
}
```

Is this possible using digester?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I suggest you read Digester documentation and post concrete question if something doesn't work as you expect it to.

Comment: ya, mostly wanted to know if its possible. I have used digester to parse basic xml, was having trouble with the nested xml...if you have any pointers it would be useful...thnx!!